# cut intersect edges

Tags: edit-mode, intersection

I want to create a hexagon using the following steps:

1. Create a plane
2. Copy it and rotate z
3. The desired output

I googled for solutions, but only found the Knife tool which entails a lot of work to cut out 8 faces, and what to do with

4. This complex cut

Is there any faster way to cut faces out of overlapping edges ?

[image: cut example]

Comment: an hexagon is a circle with 6 vertices... or you really want to make it differently ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use Knife Project to achieve shape (3). First, select the plane which defines the outline you want to cut in, then <kbd>Shift</kbd> select the plane which you want to cut and <kbd>Tab</kbd> into Edit mode. Find the tool in the Toolshelf here or in the spacebar menu:

[image: Toolbar]

Select the face in Edit Mode and execute the Knife Project Tool:

[image: before cutting]

Now delete the faces which are not needed any longer:

[image: delete these faces]

If you cut things like this a lot, you could also install the Mesh Tiny CAD addon. At the moment you can find it here: https://wiki.blender.org/index.php/Extensions:2.6/Py/Scripts/Modeling/mesh_tinyCAD

It allows to intersect vertices, faces and edges in edit mode.

Comment: thanks, the Mesh Tiny CAD addon do exactly what I want. Knife Project seems also be very useful

Answer (score 4):

There is an addon called **Boolean 2D Union** by Luxuy from BlenderCN.org can do this in a flash. It simply uses knife project operator iteratively to save the workload.

How to Use:

1. Download and install attached addon, find and enable it from File > User Preferences > Addon.
2. Select all planes then <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> <kbd>J</kbd> to join them as one single object.
3. Enter Edit Mode, make sure all faces are selected.
4. <kbd>W</kbd> > Boolean 2D Union, or search it via <kbd>Spacebar</kbd>.
5. If the mesh is a bit complex, occasionally you may need to do some clean-up work after that, such as deleting unwanted elements. But it does a pretty good job so far.

[image]

You can download it from BA thread **[here](https://blenderartists.org/forum/showthread.php?338703-Addon-Boolean-2D-Union)**.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [`Intersect (Knife)`](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/modeling/meshes/editing/face/intersect_knife.html) tool. First make sure you have intersecting faces in your object. Select an intersecting face then press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>F</kbd> then choose *Intersect (Knife)*. Now new edges get created and you can select the faces you want to remove.

[image]