# Merge objects with intersecting co-planar faces?

Tags: materials

I would like to merge intersecting faces of 2/3 polygons:

[image]

I selected all objects with A and merged them. I tried the delete duplicate method but that did not fix it. How can I merge these 3 faces so I can apply a material to that side of the object?

Comment: Remove Doubles will only work if vertices are located not far from each other and fall under the threshold of the operator. Intersecting faces can't be treated as the case for that because technically vertices which hold those faces don't intersect. I'd suggest either using font objects and retopoing them later or modeling from scratch using techniques mentioned in the answer

Comment: Unfortunately I do not know of a boolean tool that can handle full object intersections of this type (at least not well/completely).  But it may be worth looking at "Boolean 2D Union" described in this answer.  https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/60660/cut-intersect-edges  You would have to execute it separately on groups of coplanar faces (like the selected ones in your screenshot), possibly first duplicating them and  splitting into a new object.  Then you'd have to extrude or otherwise join the correctly segmented faces to your mesh.  Maybe easier just to model from scratch?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In this specific situation you can ...

- Add *Remesh modifier* (Octree 3), *Apply*
- Select all vertices and <kbd>X</kbd> *Limited Disolve*
- <kbd>W</kbd> *Merge by Distance*
- Select two vertices of hole and <kbd>X</kbd> *Disolve Vertices*

---

For some reason I lost two corner edges in N-gon (probably to much disolving :) ). 
 To fix it ...

- Select all vertices *Triangulate* <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd>
- Select all vertices and <kbd>X</kbd> *Limited Disolve* again

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Instead of starting off with bad modelling habits, like intersecting geometry and trying to fix it later, think of how to connect the pieces with proper topology.

Start with a cube, resize it on the Z axis and do two loop cuts:

[image]

Duplicate the basic shape 4 times.

[image]

Then connect the faces useing **Bridge Edge Loops**

[image]

Comment: But the thickness not match with the side and inner faces. http://pasteall.org/pic/index.php?id=127434 what will be in that condition if he need similarity

Comment: @atek would need to slide the loop cuts in step one to match the intersection locations in OP diagram. Could do it by eye, or  could use trig: left pillar top  to right pillar bottom matches the length of diagonal of the pillar.

Comment: @atek I'm outlining a way to do this with proper topology, measurements and specifics are up to the user...