# Issues with intersecting faces and how to unwrap a maze created from svg file

Tags: modeling, texturing, uv, faces

I'm pretty new to this field.I have used a svg file from maze generator to create a maze. On extruding (and applying solidify modifier), I found that several faces are overlapping and intersecting with each other, which is messing up with the textures. Is there a way to fix this? Can the 2 intersecting objects be merged as 1?[image: highlighted intersecting/overlapping faces] and how to unwrap the image?

Comment: Related: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/60660/cut-intersect-edges

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem you are facing is, that the svg from maze generator is not well suited to be imported in blender. Here the problem is, that the maze is made out of lines and not of shapes. **Basically you want to convert the outline of the lines into a shape.** This means you have to "clean" it before you can use it.

I tried it with Inkscape ([Download-page](https://inkscape.org/release)), which is free to use. But basically you can use any advanced vector-image-editor to do this, I guess.

**Using Inkscape, these are the steps which lead me success:**

1. go to Path>Object to Path (or press Shift+Ctrl+C). This will put every line into it's own object.
2. First select a line in the objects viewer and then press Ctrl+A to select everything else, since it does not seem to select all the lines if not one is selected in the first place. Then go to Path>Stroke to Path (or press Ctrl+Alt+C). This will convert the stroke, drawn by each line into a shape.

[image: select line]

3. With everything selected go to Path>Union (or press Ctrl++). This will combine all created shapes into one.
4. Now you can save the svg and import it into blender
5. In Blender you can set the thickness of the walls by changing the "offset"-value in the curve-properties

[image]

6. Then select the curve and press Alt+C to convert it into a mesh
7. Go into Edit-Mode, select all, press delete and select "Dissolve faces". This will delete all the unneeded triangle-shaped faces.

[image: dissolve faces]

8. To delete all unused point keep selected all, press delete and select "Limited Dissolve"

[image: limited dissolve]

9. If you have some ugly connections between points, just select all, press Delete and select "Only Faces", then select everything again and press F to fill the faces again.

[image]
[image]

10. Now you can extrude your mesh and have a clean maze

[image: extrude]

I hope I could help!

Comment: Thank you so much this solved the above problem. I used a 10x10 maze and i noticed that when we imported the svg it came as two curves and even after completing the steps the maze has two faces on top. is this how it should be?

Comment: Yes, (if I understood you correctly), since there are two separated meshes. You can see it if you select one point and then press Ctrl+L to select all connected points.

Comment: Hey the method works amazing when I follow it step by step. I have a few doubts though 

1) Since I require a closed maze I added two paths just to close the maze . if i add this step then when I import into blender and convert to mesh. I notice that the dissolve faces doesnt work. If i do a limited dissolve a single face gets divided into 2 triads . I believe the issue rises cause of the extra paths i added just to close the maze. If I delete that extra edge a large part of my maze lose their faces and I have to recreate all the faces by adding vertices and edges at different bends.

Comment: 2) this is just my inexperience but when it comes to UV unwrapping the maze is it alright if the  faces dont come as perfect rectangles. assuming I want to add image texture to the maze walls . what would be the correct way to proceed.