# Intersect coplanar edges with creating new vertices

Tags: vertices, edges, faces

I'm trying to switch from SketchUp to Blender and have some issues with flat surfaces.
In SketchUp if I copy any line and it intersects another it creates new point on intersection automatically. It's different in Blender and all information I found is very dated.

So basically I'm asking the same question as here: [cut intersect edges](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/60660/cut-intersect-edges)

And trying to do what is described here: https://archive.blender.org/wiki/index.php/Extensions:2.6/Py/Scripts/Modeling/mesh_tinyCAD/

[image]

I tried function 'Weld Edges into Faces' but it actually changes a shape of your surface instead of creating new vertex.

So I'm curios if any new information available which could make this task simple.

I'll be very grateful for any help!

Comment: Hello :). There is a useful *TinyCAD* addon shipped with Blender, that does exactly that. Just enable it in *Preferences > Addons*.

Comment: It's important to note that "TinyCAD only works on one objects mesh, means if you have multiple objects you need to join them by selecting them and pressing "Ctrl+J", also if you did not have the transformations applied, weird results are to be expected. Pressing "Ctrl+A" -> "All Transforms" should prevent that.

Comment: Thanks! It works! But it deletes all connected surfaces, is it normal? So you need to fill them manually with F? @Jachym Michal

Comment: @LiliaLilia I'm no expert on TinyCAD, sorry :). Feel free to post a new question about it :).