# What's the most efficient way to get rid of this overlap? (Boolean didn't work)

Tags: mesh, modifiers, boolean-modifier

I'm almost positive this is an easy fix, but rather than spending additional hours on it, I've decided to reach out! I tried to use the Boolean modifier, but it didn't do anything.
Am I using the wrong modifier? What's your best solution?

[image: original]

[image: after trying intersect (knife)]

Comment: Hello and welcome! It's quite easy. Just join the 2 objects by selecting both and pressing `ctrl`+`j`. Then `tab` into *Edit Mode* and select an intersecting face/s either the ones on the left or the ones on the right (but not both sides) and press `Ctrl`+`F` *> intersect (knife)*. Notice how they merge. then press `a` then `m` *>Merge By Distance*. See example https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/280275/142292

Comment: Thanks for your speedy response! It doesn't seem to work for me. Perhaps there's something structurally wrong with my mesh? When I try the intersect (knife) bit, nothing merges. Only extra vertices are added. (see second img above)

Comment: it shud work with any intersecting face. try a simple example first with 2 intersecting planes. select only 1 plane.

Comment: @HarryMcKenzie that sounds like an answer! post it so we can upvote it ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've managed to find my own way through this!

Here's what worked for me:

1. Create a cube, and duplicate it.
2. Merge them together so that the main cube we want is left with a frame-like shape and use the Boolean modifier.
   [image: the L is the frame-like shape we want]
3. Apply the Boolean modifier, delete the extra cube.
4. Scale/Tweak the dimensions to get desired size, then move from there with the insets and extrusions, etc.
   [image]

Here are the final results!

[image]

Answer (score 3):

This isn't really a job for a Boolean, if you can avoid it...it's modelling.

One way would be to start with a couple of quads covering the region of interest:

[image]

- <kbd>I</kbd> inset, by the thickness of the sill, and repeat, by the thickness of the inner rail.
- <kbd>X</kbd> delete the inner face.

[image]

- <kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>E</kbd> extrude all faces along normals, by the depth of the inner rail. For all extrusions, ensure 'Even Thickness' is checked.
- <kbd>Alt</kbd> Select the sill face-loop, and extrude to the depth of the sill.

For this result:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You can also join the 2 objects by selecting both and pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>J</kbd>. Then <kbd>tab</kbd> into *Edit Mode* and select an intersecting face or faces, either the ones on the left or the ones on the right (but not both sides) and press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>F</kbd> then select [`Intersect (Knife)`](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/modeling/meshes/editing/face/intersect_knife.html). Notice how they merge.

[image]

Then you can easily delete the excess geometry. Sometimes it generates other little funny geometry. Just dissolve any weird vertices that get generated.

[image]

And finally make sure to remove duplicate overlapping vertices by selecting all with <kbd>A</kbd> and pressing <kbd>M</kbd> *> Merge By Distance*.

[image]

Comment: Although this taught me how to use knife intersect (thank you!), unfortunately, it's just creating too many weird vertices/edges on my mesh. I tried it with just the two basic planes and it worked like a dream! I guess my mesh is too wonky, but I'll definitely revert back to knife intersect more in the future!

Comment: yeah I found it very useful as well! too bad it doesn't work on your mesh oh no.. XD can you share your blend file. I would like to understand what is going on with your mesh. https://blend-exchange.com